# java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 58 error

Tags: java, eclipse, cucumber, cucumber-java

When I am opening the Cucumber editor in Eclipse IDE, i am receiving the below error-

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 58
^User Selects "([^"]*)", "([^"]*)", "([^"]*)" and "([^]*)"$
```

I had received this error in an earlier execution as there was a mistake in my step definition file. I have fixed that and when I trying to open the feature file again I receive this error. Can someone help me to resolve this.The feature file and programs are attached. Even a rerun is not working.

> at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.group0(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source) at
>   cucumber.eclipse.steps.integration.Step.setText(Step.java:25) at
>   cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.jdt.StepDefinitions.getCukeAnnotations(StepDefinitions.java:230)
>   at
>   cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.jdt.StepDefinitions.getSteps(StepDefinitions.java:106)
>   at
>   cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.ExtensionRegistryStepProvider.reloadSteps(ExtensionRegistryStepProvider.java:43)
>   at
>   cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.ExtensionRegistryStepProvider.(ExtensionRegistryStepProvider.java:26)
>   at cucumber.eclipse.editor.editors.Editor.doSetInput(Editor.java:177)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor$5.run(AbstractTextEditor.java:3154)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:437)
>   at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:353)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$14.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2195)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2191)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.internalInit(AbstractTextEditor.java:3172)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.init(AbstractTextEditor.java:3197)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.initialize(EditorReference.java:362)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:333)
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor83.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:990)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:955)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:124)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:399)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:318)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:105)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:74)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:56)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:129)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:992)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:661)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:767)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:738)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:732)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42) at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:716)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1293)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.lambda$0(LazyStackRenderer.java:68)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:40)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:233)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:144)
>   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4889) at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:212)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:36)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:201)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:52)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:60)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:173)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:620)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:584)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:769)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:401)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1188)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3261)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$25(WorkbenchPage.java:3176)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3158)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3153)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3117)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3107)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:563) at
>   org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:518) at
>   org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenFileAction.openFile(OpenFileAction.java:100)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenSystemEditorAction.run(OpenSystemEditorAction.java:97)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.actions.RetargetAction.run(RetargetAction.java:216)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigatorManager$2.open(CommonNavigatorManager.java:191)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:46)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:851)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42) at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil.lambda$0(JFaceUtil.java:44) at
>   org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173) at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:848)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1163)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.handleOpen(CommonViewer.java:451)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:273)
>   at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:268)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:308)
>   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86) at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4428) at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079) at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4238)
>   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3817)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1150)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1039)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:680) at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653) at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590) at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)

[Code](https://github.com/vishalmgada/cucumberlearning.git)

Screenshot of error from Eclipse IDE while opening a feature file:
[Cucumber editor error in eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWouv.png)

Comment: How did you resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this part is wrong:

"([^])"$ - in the end of your regex

This makes no sense [^] - it means charcters that are not - and you are not saying what they shouldn't be :) For example [^a] will be charcters different from 'a' or as you have written before that [^"] - not a quote. But [^] is an error

Comment: Cucumber editor is not opening for a feature which is perfect and which was tested by me. It gives me the above error when I open it in my eclipse IDE